# How to use resource_retriever urls in command line yaml in launch script

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to display a mesh file in rviz by publishing a latched Marker message with "rostopic pub".  This works, however, when I move this into a launch script, i get errors regarding the resource_retriever url.  the launch script line:

```
<node name="$(anon robot_mesh_pub)" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" args="pub -l /robot_mesh visualization_msgs/Marker '{header: {frame_id: '/robot'}, type: 10, pose: {position: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0.2}, orientation: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5, w: 0.5}}, scale: {x: 0.001, y: 0.001, z: 0.001}, color: {r: 1.0, g: 1.0, b: 1.0, a: 1.0}, frame_locked: true, mesh_resource: package://meshes/robot.stl}'" output="screen"/>
```

I have tried to quote, and escape quote the "package://meshes/robot.stl" string in many different ways with no success.  I think the problem is that the resource_retriever protocol "package:" looks just like the yaml dictionary key.  (a string followed by a colon).  and the roslaunch parser won't let me escape the quotes properly.

3 ideas:

1. use the list format for command line yaml instead of dictionaries. (painful)
2. the resource_retriever should have a feature to also accept "regular" file paths that start with a slash.
3. this is possibly a bug in the roslaunch parser because it doesn't seem to handle escaped quotes properly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41021/how-to-use-resource_retriever-urls-in-command-line-yaml-in-launch-script/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

None of the above! You're writing XML, so you need to escape quotes the XML way: "`&quot;`"

The following worked for me:

```
    <launch>
      <node 
        name="$(anon robot_mesh_pub)" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" 
        args="pub -l /visualiztion_markers visualization_msgs/Marker '{header: {frame_id: &quot;/world&quot;}, type: 10, pose: {position: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0.2}, orientation: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5, w: 0.5}}, scale: {x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0}, color: {r: 1.0, g: 1.0, b: 1.0, a: 1.0}, frame_locked: true, mesh_resource: &quot;package://pr2_description/meshes/torso_v0/torso.stl&quot;}'" 
        output="screen"/>
    </launch>
```

Another solution, which will only work on your local machine is to use a "`$(find package_name)`" roslaunch macro. Also, the resource retriever can  use "`file://path/to/file`" URIs.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1